# Send the html content via email in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, django, html-email

I am using Django views to render an HTML(1) file that makes an AJAX request to another Django URL and the response is converted into another HTML(2). 
I want to send the contents of HTML(2) to be sent via email , is there a way to do this ?

p.s: I also have css file that defines the layout for the HTML(2). I want to ensure that the recipient can view the css formatted HTML. 
This is the code where I am creating the HTML(2).

```
 success: function(response) {
            var output  = "<ul>";
            //output += "<table border=\"1\">";
                $.each(response, function(entryIndex, entry){
                $.each(entry, function(key,value ){
                if (key != '_id'){
                if (key == 'week'){
                output += "<table border=\"1\">";
                output += "<tr>";
                output += "<th colspan=2><br>"+key+value+"</th>";
                output += "</tr>";
                //output += "</ul>";
                 }
                else{
                if ( key == 'report'){
                $.each(value, function(key1,value1){
                output += "<tr>";
                output += "<td>"+key1+" </td>";
                output += "<td>"+value1+" </td>";
                output += "</tr>";  
                });
                output += "</ul>";
                }
                }
                }
               });
               });
               output += "</ul>"; 
            $('p').html(output);
            },
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/

Comment: CSS isn't safe to use with email; especially not a separate CSS file

Answer (score 1):

In your view, you need to render HTML(2) to a string and use the vanilla Django email functionality to actually send it.

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.template.loader import render_to_string


emailBody = render_to_string('email_template.html', {'templateVars': 'values'})

send_mail('Subject here', 'emailBody, 'from@example.com', ['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

As far as the CSS piece, you either need to host that separately or embed it in the email body.  That's another subject all together.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! If you notice my question I am creating the HTML(2) based on repsonse to AJAX call within a JQuery script. I dont have access to Django modules within the script. 
I have copy pasted the section of JQuery in my "edit" to the question.

Comment: I don't think that will work if the 'finished' HTML(2) is only ever on the local client.  There's no way to trigger an email send of the content if it's only ever rendered locally because of obvious security implications that would have.  You'd need to restructure like above so the 'finished' HTML(2) is on the server and can be sent all server-side.